# Understand the output of eth-gas-reporter

Tags: gas, gas-price, hardhat, gas-estimate, test

So, I am using the [eth-gas-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-gas-reporter) package to understand how much gas functions costs (via hardhat test). But I don't understand the output. What is the meaning of `5 gwei/gas`,`calls`, what are the numbers mean? Below is the output that I get:

```
·--------------------------|---------------------------|--------------|-----------------------------·
|   Solc version: 0.8.4    ·  Optimizer enabled: true  ·  Runs: 1000  ·  Block limit: 12450000 gas  │
···························|···························|··············|······························
|  Methods                 ·                5 gwei/gas                ·       2875.76 eur/eth       │
·············|·············|·············|·············|··············|···············|··············
|  Contract  ·  Method     ·  Min        ·  Max        ·  Avg         ·  # calls      ·  eur (avg)  │
·············|·············|·············|·············|··············|···············|··············
|  LazyNFT   ·  grantRole  ·          -  ·          -  ·       51386  ·           13  ·       0.74  │
·············|·············|·············|·············|··············|···············|··············
|  LazyNFT   ·  redeem     ·     212579  ·     272375  ·      251672  ·           26  ·       3.62  │
·············|·············|·············|·············|··············|···············|··············
|  LazyNFT   ·  withdraw   ·          -  ·          -  ·       18241  ·            6  ·       0.26  │
·············|·············|·············|·············|··············|···············|··············
|  Deployments             ·                                          ·  % of limit   ·             │
···························|·············|·············|··············|···············|··············
|  LazyNFT                 ·          -  ·          -  ·     2517874  ·       20.2 %  ·      36.20  │
·--------------------------|-------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|-------------·
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows you the different methods of your contract and their gas consumption.

For each function that you tested, it shows the minimum gas spent for that function, the maximum, and the average.

> 1 gwei = 0.000000001 ether

On your result, it shows that you're paying **5 gwei/gas** for **2875.76 eur/eth**, it is the recommended amount of gwei, you can check this website to have the current gas price [EthGasStation](https://ethgasstation.info/)

### Calculation

`0.000000001 eth (1gwei) * 5 = 5gwei` *(recommendation at the moment of your test)*

---

so `0.000000005 = 5gwei`

`251672 gas` (avg gas spent for redeem function)

---

`0.000000005 * 251672 = 0.00125836 ETH`

`0.00125836*2875.76 (eth price in eur) = 3.6187413536 eur ~= 3.62 eur`

Answer (score 0):

Thats just the gas price you're using to calculate out the eur costs.